# Find elements in two JavaScript arrays and store each array with its own different ones

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of contacts from two arrays. Some of the elements maybe the same, but I need to know which array has unique values and keep those unique values in that array. In other words, I want to track the unique values from which array they came from. This is my spaghetti code that I have so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i < emailNews.length; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < emailHealth.length; j++) 
                {
                    if (emailNews[i] == emailHealth[j]) {
                        $('#userList').append(descriptionNews[i] + '<td><span style="margin-right: 5px;">Advanced</span><input type="checkbox" name="advanced" id="advancedCheck" checked></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-user-delete" id="' + userLogin + '" >Delete</button></td></tr>');
                   } else {
                       console.log(descriptionHealth[j]);
                       $("#userList").append(descriptionHealth[j] + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteEnd">Delete</button></td></tr>');
                    }
                }

        }
```

Comment: Is requirement to remove duplicate elements from an array?

Comment: yes, but I need to know which arrays contains which unique ones

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "which arrays contains which unique ones"?

Comment: both arrays are from two lists of emails. I need to print to HTML if the specific user is contained in both lists. If not, then which list is the differing value coming from

Comment: please add some data and what you like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little confusing, but as I understand, you have two arrays, and you wish to know the unique items in each array (items not in the other array).

So given arrays `a` and `b`, you could create two new arrays that hold just the unique ones.

```js
// unique--v---------------------v
var a = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "zing"];

// unique--v
var b = ["oof", "bar", "baz"];

var unique_a = a.filter(item => !b.includes(item));
var unique_b = b.filter(item => !a.includes(item));

console.log("Unique in `a`: %s", JSON.stringify(unique_a));
console.log("Unique in `b`: %s", JSON.stringify(unique_b));
```

So now that you have your unique values, and you know which array they came from, you can do what you need with those values.

---

If you want to do it while you're looping, that's just as easy. Just take the other array and call `.includes()` on it with the current item.

```
a.forEach(item => {
  if (b.includes(item)) {
    // not unique...
  } else {
    // unique
  }
});
```

---

If you need to work with all items, separating out the unique ones both ways, then also working with the shared ones, make a `Set` of all, and iterate that.

```
for (const item of new Set([...a, ...b])) {
  var in_a = a.includes(item);
  var in_b = b.includes(item);
  if (in_a && in_b) {
    // not unique
  } else if (in_a) {
    // unique to 'a'
  } else {
    // unique to 'b'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is to remove duplicate elements from one or more arrays you can use `$.unique()`. Set arrays as properties of objects and include a property which uniquely identifies the current object

```js
(() => {
  let arr1 = {
    arr: [2, 2, 3],
    name: "arr1"
  };

  let arr2 = {
    arr: [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    name: "arr2"
  };

  let res;

  let user = 1;

  if (arr1.arr.indexOf(user) > -1 && arr2.arr.indexOf(user) > -1) {

    res = $.unique($.map([arr1.arr, arr2.arr], arr => arr))

  } else {
    for (let o of Object.values([arr1, arr2])) {
      if (!o.arr.indexOf(user) > -1) {
        res = o.name + " does not contain " + user;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(res);

})();

(() => {
  let arr1 = {
    arr: [1, 2, 2, 3],
    name: "arr1"
  };

  let arr2 = {
    arr: [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    name: "arr2"
  };

  let res;

  let user = 1;

  if (arr1.arr.indexOf(user) > -1 && arr2.arr.indexOf(user) > -1) {
    res = $.unique($.map([arr1.arr, arr2.arr], arr => arr))

  } else {
    for (let o of Object.values([arr1, arr2])) {
      if (!o.arr.indexOf(user) > -1) {
        res = o.name + " does not contain " + user;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(res);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```